# How to execute several times a job with a changing parameter on gitlab-ci

Tags: ios, gitlab-ci

I would like to execute the same testing job for several iOS version on gitlab-ci.

My testing job is composed of the following command:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace myproject.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6S,OS=9.3'
```

Is it possible to create a kind of loop to execute this command for different OS versions and iPhone/iPad?

For exemple, doing an xcodebuild test for :

- iPhone 6 / iOS 9.3
- iPhone 6 / iOS 10.0
- iPhone 7 / iOS 10.0
- iPad Mini / iOS 8.2
- iPad Mini / iOS 9.3 ....

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

With versions >=13.5 you can use a [parallel:matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) to execute a job many times in parallel with values.

For your example:

```
Test:ios:
  stage: test
  script:
    - xcodebuild test -workspace myproject.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=${DEVICE},OS=${VERSION}'
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DEVICE: 'iPhone 6'
        VERSION: ['9.3', '10.0']
      - DEVICE: 'iPhone 7'
        VERSION: ['10.0']
      - DEVICE: 'iPad Mini'
        VERSION: ['8.2', '9.3']
```

Answer (score 7):

Use gitlab-ci `template` and define one variable which contains the name of the simulator, for example, with an iPhone 5S:

```
# Job
.test_ios_job: &test_ios_job_def
      stage: test_ios
      script:
            - xcodebuild test -workspace myproject.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=$SIMULATOR'

# iPhone 5S

test_ios_iPhone5S_9.1:
      <<: *test_ios_job_def
      variables:
          SIMULATOR: "iPhone 5S,OS=9.1"

test_ios_iPhone5S_10.1:
      <<: *test_ios_job_def
      variables:
          SIMULATOR: "iPhone 5S,OS=10.1"
```

I would recommend to use `fastlane`, plugin `scan` to simplify the work:

```
# Job
.test_ios_job: &test_ios_job_def
      stage: test_ios
      script:
            - fastlane testios emulatorname:"$SIMULATOR"

test_ios_iPhone5S_9.1:
      <<: *test_ios_job_def
      variables:
          SIMULATOR: "iPhone 5s (9.1)"

test_ios_iPhone5S_10.1:
      <<: *test_ios_job_def
      variables:
          SIMULATOR: "iPhone 5s (10.1)"
```

fastlane job:

```
lane :testios  do |options|
emulatorname = options[:emulatorname]

#Scan
scan(
    scheme: S_APP_SCHEME_TEST,
    clean: true,
    device: "#{emulatorname.to_s}",
)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like this, it is pseudo-code and not the dry-est but it works, i.e. it runs same job in sequence with different parameters:

```
job: # generic job
  variables:
    X: "x"

job-y: # job runs with variable = y
  extends: job
  variables:
    X: "y"

job-z: # job runs with variable = z
  extends: job
  variables:
    X: "z"

job-yz: # execs job sequentially with 2 variable values
  extends: 
    - job-y
    - job-z
```

Answer (score -5):

Use stages:

```
stages:
  - buildForiPhone
  - buildForiPad

build_project:
  stage: buildForiPhone
  script:
    - xcodebuild for iPhone here
  tags:
    - Swift
    - iOS9

build_project:
  stage: buildForiPad
  script:
    - xcodebuild for iPad here
  tags:
    - Swift
    - iOS9
```

> **One stage** for **one build_project**,and they are `isolated`.

Comment: My question was more about executing the same job for several versions of devices and iOS without duplicating the jobs and stages.

For exemple, doing an `xcodebuild test` for :
- iPhone 6 / iOS 9.3
- iPhone 6 / iOS 10.0
- iPhone 7 / iOS 10.0
- iPad Mini / iOS 8.2
- iPad Mini / iOS 9.3
 ....